# Bloc scroll top after scroll 100vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a homepage with a 100vh div at the top, and I would like to hide it when you scroll down after this div. Or disable the posibility to scroll up after scrolling this 100vh div. This div should only appear once when you arrived on the website.

Here the link : http://tmp.thomasdesnoyers.com/
After the big coloured background div you shloudn't be able to scroll up.

I tried to add a 'display:none' proprety to this div after scrolling the height of the window but it has the effect of take all the content up...
If anybody have any clues on this…

This the div to hide :

```
<div id="home-background" class="monobg">


<?php $images_toomany = array("/wp-content/img/toomany.svg", "/wp-
content/img/toomany_2.svg", "/wp-content/img/toomany_3.svg", "/wp-
content/img/toomany_4.svg", "/wp-content/img/toomany_5.svg");?>
<?php echo '<img src="'.$images_toomany[array_rand($images_toomany)].'" 
class="toomany" />';?>

<?php $images_pictures = array("/wp-content/img/pictures.svg", "/wp-
content/img/pictures_2.svg", "/wp-content/img/pictures_3.svg", "/wp-
content/img/pictures_4.svg", "/wp-content/img/pictures_5.svg",);?>
<?php echo '<img src="'.$images_pictures[array_rand($images_pictures)].'" 
class="pictures" />';?>


</div>
```

Thank you.

Thomas

Comment: Please post your code, thanks

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"* - [What topics can I ask about on Stack Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Just edit my post with the code of the div to hide

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Super simple. Just add overflow:hidden to your body element when you want to prevent scrolling beyond the current viewport. You can do this dynamically via JS or jQuery.

Comment: It allows scrolling by Arrow-Keys, for example.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Overflow:Hidden on the body will prevent scrolling via both keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Just add it to the body and it do the opposite. It display just the home-background div which I want to hide and hide the rest of the page.

Comment: It will lock your current viewport - so you wont want to apply it until you have scrolled to the point you want to lock the scrolling.

Comment: Just post my JS code in answer, almost there I think

Comment: Side note. I don't like to recommend plugins, but in this case it might be the way to go. If you are trying to make it so that each section locks into place as you scroll, fullpage.js will do this for you with just a couple lines of script and adding the proper section tags.

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: @Korgrue It will not prevent keyboard scrolling, at least it does not in some major browsers afaik.

Comment: Just tested it using his site on Chrome, FF, and IE and it works as intended on them.

Comment: I thought use the overflow hidden and also calculate the height of the page in js to put on the body

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var div_height = $('#home-background').height();    
    var page_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(page_scroll > div_height) {
        $('#home-background').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.
The only problem with this technics is it's take all the content up because the big div at the top no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

here my code with the overflow technic.
I think it's a good start :

```
jQuery(function($) {

var $nav = $('body');
var $win = $(window);
var winH = $win.height(); // Get the window height.

$win.on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > winH ) {
        $nav.addClass("hide");
    } 
}).on("resize", function(){ // If the user resizes the window
   winH = $(this).height(); // you'll need the new height value
});

});
```